# How to integrate code compilers for various programming languages in react js web application?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux

I am developing a quiz web application using react js. How can I integrate diffrent compilers, so that users can write and compile their code in different languages like javascript, python and others. What are option available. Is there any ready made services to integrate the compilers in react web application?

Comment: are you building a quiz website?

Comment: Yes. It will have coding questions as well

Comment: then you should have a set of fixed answers instead of install language compliers. having language compliers in your project is overkill. java complier alone is like 200mb plus.

Comment: The code can be written in many ways we cannot have one fixed anwer. So what we need is a compiler where user can write his code and compile in a desired language. And after submitting we will be checking the code mannually